# Trying to write a code that prints five numbers from greatest to least without using loops

Tags: java

I have tried everything, but i cannot get this code to print the 5 numbers in order from greatest to least. Any help will be appriciated.  The java website tells me to write more so here it goes. I would use a loop to achieve this, but the task requires that loops are not used. I am having trouble with printing out these 5 numbers from greatest to least without using loops. Please help

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InOrder{

    public static void main(String[] args){ 

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int hi=0;
        int hi2=0;
        int mid=0;
        int low=0;
        int low2=0;

        System.out.println("Enter 5 variables:");
        int num1 = input.nextInt();
        int num2 = input.nextInt();
        int num3 = input.nextInt();
        int num4 = input.nextInt();
        int num5 = input.nextInt();

        //Finds the highest number
        if ((num1 >= num2) && (num1 >= num3) && (num1 >= num4) && (num1 >= num5)) {
            hi = num1;
        } else if ((num2 >= num1) && (num2 >= num3) && (num2 >= num4) && (num2 >= num5)) {
            hi = num2;
        } else if ((num3 >= num1) && (num3 >= num2) && (num3 >= num4) && (num3 >=  num5)) {
            hi = num3;
        } else if ((num4 >= num1) && (num4 >= num2) && (num4 >= num3) && (num4 >= num5)) {
            hi = num4;
        } else if ((num5 >= num1) && (num5 >= num2) && (num5 >= num3) && (num5 >= num4)) {
            hi = num5;
        }

        // Finds Second Highest
        if ((num1 > mid) && (num1 > low) && (num1 > low2) && (num1 < hi)) {
            hi2 = num1;
        } else if ((num2 > mid) && (num2 > low) && (num2 > low2) && (num2 < hi)) {
            hi2 = num2;
        } else if ((num3 > mid) && (num3 > low) && (num3 > low2) && (num3 < hi)) {
            hi2 = num3;
        } else if ((num4 > mid) && (num4 > low) && (num4 > low2) && (num4 < hi)) {
            hi2 = num4;
        } else if ((num5 > mid) && (num5 > low) && (num5 > low2) && (num5 < hi)) {
            hi2 = num5;
        }

        //Finds the middle number
        if ((num1 < hi) && (num1 < hi2) && (num1 > low2) && (num1 > low)) {
            mid = num1;
        } else if ((num2 < hi) && (num2 < hi2) && (num2 > low2) && (num2 > low)) {
            mid = num2;
        } else if ((num3 < hi) && (num3 < hi2) && (num3 > low2) && (num3 > low)) {
            mid = num3;
        } else if ((num4 < hi) && (num4 < hi2) && (num4 > low2) && (num4 > low)) {
            mid = num4;
        } else if ((num5 < hi) && (num5 < hi2) && (num5 > low2) && (num5 > low)) {
            mid = num5;
        }

        //Finds the lowest number
        if ((num1 <= num2) && (num1 <= num3) && (num1 <= num4) && (num1 <= num5)) {
            low = num1;
        } else if ((num2 <= num1) && (num2 <= num3) && (num2 <= num4) && (num2 <=  num5)) {
            low = num2;
        } else if ((num3 <= num1) && (num3 <= num2) && (num3 <= num4) && (num3 <= num5)) {
            low = num3;
        } else if ((num4 <= num1) && (num4 <= num2) && (num4 <= num3) && (num4 <= num5)) {
            low = num4;
        } else if ((num5 <= num1) && (num5 <= num2) && (num5 <= num3) && (num5 <= num4)) {
            low = num5;
        }

        //Finds Second Lowest
        if ((num1 < mid) && (num1 > low) && (num1 < hi2) && (num1 < hi)) {
            low2 = num1;
        } else if ((num2 < mid) && (num2 > low) && (num2 < hi2) && (num2 < hi)) {
            low2 = num2;
        } else if ((num3 < mid) && (num3 > low) && (num3 < hi2) && (num3 < hi)) {
            low2 = num3;
        } else if ((num4 < mid) && (num4 > low) && (num4 < hi2) && (num4 < hi)) {
            low2 = num4;
        } else if ((num5 < mid) && (num5 > low) && (num5 < hi2) && (num5 < hi)) {
            low2 = num5;
        }

        System.out.println("The variables from greatest to least are:");
        System.out.print("" + hi);
        System.out.print("," + hi2);
        System.out.print("," + mid);
        System.out.print("," + low2);
        System.out.print("," + low);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are supposed to make use of a _recurive_ method.

Comment: You can use a sorting algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: The fact is that a recursive method is still looping in a way -- its just looping method invocations instead of using a for declaration.  Roman Graf's answer will likely result in the fastest processing 9/10 times.

Comment: Thank you for this, but is there anyway i can utilize a scanner so that i can imput the numbers and it returns them from greatest to least. I am very new to java and it baffles me that there isnt a simpler way to return five numbers from greatest to least. Is my code editable to achive this?

Answer (score 2):

Also with Roman Graf's answer
You need to include this at the top of the document

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Try doing something like this:

```
    public class NoLoopSort {
        static int[] values = new int[] { 4, 2, 5, 1, 3 };
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            printLower(0, values.length - 1);
            printLower(0, values.length - 1);
            printLower(0, values.length - 1);
            printLower(0, values.length - 1);
            printLower(0, values.length - 1);
        }

        private static void printLower(int start, int end) {
            if (start == end) {
                // this is currently the lowest number in array, print it.
                System.out.println(values[start]);
                // make current index biggest possible
                values[start] = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
            } else {
                if (values[start] < values[end]) {
                    printLower(start, end - 1);
                } else if (values[start] >= values[end]) {
                    printLower(start + 1, end);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The above is a recursive swapping function that basically just starts off at the beginnning and then checks if the next number in an array is larger or smaller, if its smaller than it swaps the two and starts over, otherwise it moves on to the next number.

**[edit]** java code replaced with tested version.

Comment: Thank you for this, but is there anyway i can utilize a scanner so that i can imput the numbers and it returns them from greatest to least. I am very new to java and it baffles me that there isnt a simpler way to return five numbers from greatest to least. Is my code editable to achive this?

Comment: @Carl  you could easily apply the tactics used in Roman Graf's code to do that

Simply set up your `num1, num2, num3`  with scanner and then change the values in the `int[]` named `values` to `num1`, `num2` etc etc

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use loops?

```
System.out.println(Arrays.sort(new int[]{num1,num2,num3,num4,num5}));
```

A little bit cheaty. You create an Array and sort this array using APIs. Or is it forbidden to call functions that use loops?

Comment: that's kinda cheating since both `Arrays.sort` as well as `Array.toString` work with loops internally.

Comment: `Arrays.sort()` is a `void` method.